# smallest element -> highest percentage

Tags: probability

I have a set of numbers $Q = \lbrace q_1, ..., q_n \rbrace$ and want to assign weights $w_i$ to each element $q_i$ such that the weights add up to one. However, I'd like to assign the highest weight to the smallest element in the set.

I came up with this solution:

\begin{align}
w_i &= \frac{1 - \frac{q_i}{\sum_{q \in Q} q}}{n - 1} 
    = \frac{(\sum_{q \in Q} q) - q_i}{(n - 1) \cdot \sum_{q\in Q} q}
\end{align}

The rationale is that I first calculate the inverted percentage of element $q_i$ and divide it by $n - 1$ to normalize the weight.

What do you think about this solution? Do you think, it's practicable or are there better approaches?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If $Q$ is sorted, can't we have $w_i = \frac{q_{n-i+1}}{\sum_{i}^n q_i}$?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to do that. How do you decide which is better? What you suggest would work, but so would $w_i=\frac {q_{n+1-i}}{\sum_{q\in Q}q} $.

Comment: @user8734617 I wanted to confirm that is solution is ok because I was a bit sceptical about it (because you can interpret it as the average of all elements except for $q_i$ divided by the sum of all elements, so, it's somehow the normalized mean of all elements except $q_i$). Moreover, I was looking for a more concise, maybe a bit more intelligent alternative.

Comment: My hint here is identical to @TiwaAina 's answer, but you had different concerns about the two. I didn't want to post mine as an answer because I was not sure what you have been looking for. How do you measure whether the solution is more or less intelligent, for instance? As for your concern about Tiwa Aina's solution, of course $w_i $ depends not only on $q_i $ but on all $q $'s, but so does *your* solution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I didn't really understood the main idea behind @TiwaAina 's answer. - Of course, I have no measurement for "intelligent" solution because it's somehow a matter of opinion. However, I do not want to put to much weight on the question how to evaluate the quality of an answer and just focus on the set of possible solutions. Feel free to post your solution, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all $q_i \ne 0$, you could try
$$ w_i = \frac{1/q_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n 1/q_j} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, introduction601. This looks very good. My use case does not explicitly states that $q_i \neq 0$, but in practice, this may hold.

Answer (score 0):

If $Q$ is sorted, you could use $$w_i = \frac{q_{n-i+1}}{\sum_{i}^n q_i}$$

There are tons of weighting methods that would fit your criteria, but I imagine that this is the simplest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tiwa. Actually, $Q$ is not sorted and can contain arbitrary numbers $q_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. I'd like to avoid sorting because the complexity of my algorithm would become at least $\mathcal{O}(n\cdot \log n)$. 

However, I do not really understand the rationale of this equation. Can you please explain it shortly? As far as I can see, $w_i$ depends in this equation on number $q_{n-i+1}$. But I wanted to make it depending on the number $q_i$, i.e., $w_i = f(q_i)$